# Application publishing both REST and SOAP API with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, rest, soap, spring-boot

I Have a Spring Boot application with RestController, service, and domain. So my application publishes a REST API. How would I go about to have my application publish both a REST and a SOAP API at the same time? Thanks!

Comment: You write the SOAP Api? Seriously though, there is no magic switch that will make your application a SOAP application.

Comment: I mean, do I just implement it alongside the REST API, or do I need some additional interceptors or something here?

Comment: You can just use Controllers like you have been doing and implement it alongside everything else. You might want to look at the Documentation for `@RequestMapping` more, especially the `consumes` and `produces` attributes. Spring Boot will configure Jackson to output XML as well, when you use these attributes.

Comment: Don't use a controller for that, use Spring WS for that. You don't want to manually mangle the SOAP stuff, nor want to reinvent the wheel I suspect.